# using array and loops to display outputs

Tags: c++

I am doing a workshop and I am stuck on this program. we are supposed to make an array of distances ran and have an array of days of the week.then display the total ran for the week, the average ran, and shortest day ran for the week. data pulled from the arrays. one array for the days, one arrays for the miles ran. Use separate loops when inputting times, calculating the total distance, and finding the day with the shortest distance run

sunday = 2. mon= 5. tues=3.5. wed= 1.5. thur= 6. fri=8. sat=2.5.

const int SIZE = 7; //number of days
    const string WEEK[] = {"Sunday",
                           "Monday",
                           "Tuesday",
                           "Wednesday",
                           "Thursday",
                           "Friday",
                           "Saturday"};

```
double distances[SIZE];
double total = 0,
       average;
int shortest_index = 0;

cout << "Please enter the distance run." << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    cout << WEEK[i] << "  : ";
    // Do: Take user input for distance HERE
}

// Do: Determine the total and average number of miles run

// Do: Determine the index of the day with the lowest miles



cout << fixed << setprecision(2)
     << "Total distance  : " << total << endl
     << "Average distance : " << average << endl
     << "Shortest distance : " << distances[shortest_index] << " miles on " << WEEK[shortest_index] << endl;
```

I am confused how to write this. any help is awesome!

Comment: (https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/63-arrays-and-loops/)

Comment: Please show us your code so far. We have no idea what your skill level is. If you show us your best attempt at getting this to work, we can focus on the parts you need help with.

Comment: Why do you need more than one array?

Comment: @JohnFilleau it had been updated with my code and new comments go clarify my question

Comment: You need to learn how to store user input in an array? There are questions on that on this website with answers already. You need to calculate the sum and average of an array? Same. You need to find the index where a min value occurs? Same. Please do some searching and explain in your question why (not "that", but "why") those other questions don't solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using two arrays:

```
static const char day_names[] =
{
    "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
    "Friday", "Saturday"
};
static const unsigned int day_quantity =
    sizeof(day_names) / sizeof(day_names[0]);

double mileage[day_quantity];
double shortest_distance = 10000000.0;
unsigned int index_shortest_distance = 0U;
double total_distance = 0.0;

for (unsigned int i = 0U; i < day_quantity; ++i)
{
    std::cout << "Enter mileage for "
              << day_names[i]
              << ": ";
    double distance = 0.0;
    std::cin >> distance;
    total_distance += distance;
    mileage[i] = distance;
    if (distance < shortest_distance)
    {
         shortest_distance = distance;
         index_shortest_distance = i;
    }
}

std::cout << "Total distance: " << total_distance << "\n"
std::cout << "Shortest distance:  "
          << shortest_disance
          << ", occured on "
          << day_names[index_shortest_distance]
          << "\n";
std::cout << "Average distance: "
          << (total_distance / day_quantity)
          << "\n";
for (unsigned int i = 0U; i < day_quantity; ++i)
{
    std::cout << day_names[i] << ": " << mileage[i] << "\n";
}
```

The above code keeps a running total and a running minimum (shortest) distance.  The "stats" are then printed.

Comment: i guess to be more clear i would need help getting the input storing into arrays and then having the loop to display the required output

Comment: we need two arrays one for the distances the user inputs which is the miles than ran. the second array is for the days of the week. then call on the arrays to get the values needed for the output.

Comment: this is the program we are supposed to write. (create a workout tracking program that lets the user enter (from the console) the distance they ran each day of the week. Store each value into an array of doubles named distances.  •The program should calculate and display to the screen ◦The total distance run for the week. ◦The average distance run for the week. ◦The shortest distance and day.•Use separate loops when inputting times, calculating the total distance, and finding the day with the shortest distance run)

Comment: Which part of the requirements did I not implement?  The `day_names` is the *array for the days of the week*.  The `mileage` array is for the *distances the user inputs".  Put my code inside a `main()` function, then walk through it with a debugger.  If you are brave, you can run it without the debugger.

Comment: I'm not writing code for you to give to your instructor.  You are going to have to do some work for yourself.  If you want to use more loops, i.e. *Use separate loops...*,  then go ahead and modify the code to do so.  I didn't see the need for those *separate loops*, so I didn't implement them; makes the code more efficient.